# Arduino Keyboard starts lower case (but it shouldn't)

Tags: arduino-leonardo, keyboard, atmega32u4, hid

So I flashed the [KeyboardMessage](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/KeyboardMessage) example to my [Arduino SS Micro ATmega32U4](https://circuit.rocks/ss-micro-atmega32u4-arduino-compatible.html).

When I open an editor and push the button, I would assume the output to be

> Zou pressed the button XX times.

(The "Z" is because I use a German keyboard)

In some editors (Arduino IDE, LibreOffice) this assumption is fulfilled.

However, in several other editors (Linux Shell, gedit), **most of the times** the output is

> zou pressed the button 1 times.

starting with a lower case "z".

I use a Debian Testing computer. The only thing I changed in the sketch was the `buttonPin` as my button is soldered to pin 11.

I noticed, that this problem doesn't occur when the button is pressed a second time shortly after the first message. To investigate this, I coded a [little sketch](https://gist.github.com/speendo/c4001a6bf2fdecce148a2c1094cc10fd) to find the threshold.

This is what I got (in gedit)

[image: output]

As line 8 shows, even after 70 millis, the upper case start is not reliable, however, somewhere after 250 millis, the error occurs every time.

My questions are:

1. What could be the cause for this issue?
2. How can it be fixed (if necessary, I also welcome a workaround)?

Please tell me if you need any additional information.

[edit]
After slightly altering the script, I noticed, that the problem doesn't only occur on the start of a line, but also (although less often) later in the output. See lines 24, 31 and 52 for example

[image]

Comment: Probable a long shot, but do you have any gedit plugins (e.g. ChangeCase plugin) enabled? Also, I hate to be pedantic, but are you sure the "little sketch" matches the output? The "little sketch" has a space between the number and millis (i.e. should produce "90 millis", not "90millis" as shown above). Also, the "little sketch" outputs a capital M in Message - which are all lower case in the above example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I indeed do have some gedit plugins enabled, however, they shouldn't change the case. I tried in the Linux shell as well and had the same result. About the changes in the sketch: you are right - I changed these two things after running the sketch. However, I didn't want to run it again as this takes quite some time.

Comment: yes, i just reread and saw the comment about linux shell. Oh, well it was a long shot :-)

Comment: Without any knowledge in this area, i assume that "slow editors" work better than "fast editors" and that somehow the shift key is swallowed somewhere between the arduino and the computer.

Comment: What happens if you unplug your normal keyboard while it's running?

Comment: @Majenko just tried: it's exactly the same.

Comment: As a debugging aid, you may try to use `xev` to see the keyboards events. When I press Shift-Y on my keyboard, `xev` shows four distinct events: KeyPress(Shift\_L), KeyPress(Y), KeyRelease(Y), KeyRelease(Shift\_L). Do you see the same events in the same order? See also [Keyboard input](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_input) in the Arch Linux Wiki (instructive even if you are not using Arch).

Comment: use keyboard.press() and keyboard.release() to send the shift key states at the correct time

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @EdgarBonet thanks for the `xev` tip. I coded a small sketch that should print "ON" when I push a button on the Arduino. This is the output in xev: https://nopaste.xyz/?b4efb9869c386975#22qZaCvBxQ2HfuTxEGszxdxnLbf18qTNuuCToR9JfwpA . In an editor like gedit this reads like "oN"

Comment: @jsotola this would be a possible workaround. However, like this I would need to distinguish between those characters that need a shift button and those that don't. Something I hoped the keyboard library would do for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I have the answer to your problem, just a collection of
observations that hopefully steer you in the right direction.

According to your nopaste link, when you send "ON", the first four
keyboard events received by `xev` are: press(Shift_L), press(O),
release(Shift_L), release(o). One may notice that there is no point in
releasing the Shift key if it's going to be pressed again right away,
but let's assume that simply holding Shift is not such a useful
optimization. The detail that strikes me is that the last two events
look backwards: you usually release the letter *before* releasing Shift.
As a result of releasing Shift first, the release event for the O key
reports lowercase "o" as a keysym. I tried this backward way of
releasing the keys on a real keyboard, but both gnome-terminal and gedit
correctly registered the uppercase letters.

Another detail apparent in the xev dump is that the two key presses
(Shit and O) happen at the exact same time. Ditto for the corresponding
key releases. Looking at the source of the Keyboard library, it appears
that both key presses are sent to the PC as a single "key report". Same
for the key releases. This is contrary to what a real keyboard does:
actuations on the Shift keys are reported immediately, irrespective of
whether other keys are actuated.

You may try to modify the Keyboard library so that the actuations on
Shift are sent in their own reports. Maybe something like this
(**warning**: completely untested):

```
diff --git a/src/Keyboard.cpp b/src/Keyboard.cpp
index 4a948f6..9fbf7b6 100644
--- a/src/Keyboard.cpp
+++ b/src/Keyboard.cpp
@@ -239,6 +239,7 @@ size_t Keyboard_::press(uint8_t k)
        }
        if (k & 0x80) {                     // it's a capital letter or other character reached with shift
            _keyReport.modifiers |= 0x02;   // the left shift modifier
+           sendReport(&_keyReport);        // send the shift key by itself
            k &= 0x7F;
        }
    }
@@ -270,6 +271,7 @@ size_t Keyboard_::press(uint8_t k)
 size_t Keyboard_::release(uint8_t k) 
 {
    uint8_t i;
+   bool has_shift = false;
    if (k >= 136) {         // it's a non-printing key (not a modifier)
        k = k - 136;
    } else if (k >= 128) {  // it's a modifier key
@@ -281,7 +283,7 @@ size_t Keyboard_::release(uint8_t k)
            return 0;
        }
        if (k & 0x80) {                         // it's a capital letter or other character reached with shift
-           _keyReport.modifiers &= ~(0x02);    // the left shift modifier
+           has_shift = true;
            k &= 0x7F;
        }
    }
@@ -295,6 +297,10 @@ size_t Keyboard_::release(uint8_t k)
    }
 
    sendReport(&_keyReport);
+   if (has_shift) {
+       _keyReport.modifiers &= ~(0x02);    // the left shift modifier
+       sendReport(&_keyReport);            // release shift after releasing the letter
+   }
    return 1;
 }
```

Alternatively, as suggested by @jstola in a comment, you may try to
press the Shift key by itself. Maybe you don't need to care about the
key release, or about any character but the first one (as it is the only
one that seems to cause problems). A minimal workaround to try would be:

```cpp
Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);
Keyboard.println("ON");
```

Comment: Thanks, @EdgarBonet! I can confirm, that your solution works on my computer. However, this raises the question if the "original" Arduino implementation is faulty. I would encourage you to file a pull request on their implementation.

Comment: by the way, the problem doesn't only occur in the first character but also sometimes on later ones.

Comment: @speendo: I am reluctant to submit a pull request, as I do not have a 32U4-based Arduino to test it. I would do it, though, if you are willing to help with the testing: provide a minimal test sketch, run it, and report the results on the pull request page.

Comment: Of course I am willing to help. Using this library (https://github.com/NicoHood/HID) you could also use test your code with another Arduino board (this is the library where I first experienced the error) But I would also fund you a cheap Pro Micro board as a little recognition for your work. Just tell me what solution(s) you like best :)